# EF Core 2.1 Updating related entites query efficiency

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

I'm having a student model in which i have list of phone numbers and addresses.When i update the  student the related data(phone and address) needs to be updated. I have written a PUT action in my student controller for that. It works fine, but I'm concerned about the efficiency of the query. Please check the code and suggest me improvisation if any. Thanks

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Put(long id, [FromBody] Student student)
    {
        var p = await _Context.Students
            .Include(t => t.PhoneNumbers)
            .Include(t => t.Addresses)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(t => t.Id == id);

        if (p == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        _Context.Entry(p).CurrentValues.SetValues(student);

        #region PhoneNumber
        var existingPhoneNumbers = p.PhoneNumbers.ToList();
        foreach (var existingPhone in existingPhoneNumbers)
        {
            var phoneNumber = student.PhoneNumbers.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == existingPhone.Id);
            if (phoneNumber != null)
                _Context.Entry(existingPhone).CurrentValues.SetValues(phoneNumber);
            else
                _Context.Remove(existingPhone);
        }
        // add the new items
        foreach (var phoneNumber in student.PhoneNumbers)
        {
            if (existingPhoneNumbers.All(i => i.Id != phoneNumber.Id))
            {
                p.PhoneNumbers.Add(phoneNumber);
            }
        }
        #endregion


        #region Address
        var existingAddresses = p.Addresses.ToList();
        foreach (var existingAddress in existingAddresses)
        {
            var address = student.Addresses.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == existingAddress.Id);
            if (address != null)
                _Context.Entry(existingAddress).CurrentValues.SetValues(address);
            else
                _Context.Remove(existingAddress);
        }
        // add the new items
        foreach (var address in student.Addresses)
        {
            if (existingAddresses.All(i => i.Id != address.Id))
            {
                p.Addresses.Add(address);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        await _Context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return NoContent();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching over small in-memory collections is not normally something you would worry about.  So if a Student has dozens or hundreds of addresses, the repeated lookups are not going to be significant, especially compared with the time required to write to the database.

If you did want to optimize, you can copy the students Addresses to a Dictionary.  Like this:

```
    var existingAddresses = p.Addresses.ToList();
    var studentAddresses = student.Addresses.ToDictionary(i => i.Id);
    foreach (var existingAddress in existingAddresses)
    {
        if (studentAddresses.TryGetValue(existingAddress.Id, out Address address))
        {
            _Context.Entry(existingAddress).CurrentValues.SetValues(address);
        }
        else
        {
            _Context.Remove(existingAddress);
        }
    }
```

A query over an in-memory collection like this:

```
var address = student.Addresses.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Id == existingAddress.Id);
```

Will simply iterate all the student.Addresses comparint the Ids.  A Dictionary<> acts like an index, providing very fast lookups.